# Cant run rails server on downloaded github file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I downloaded a file from github (https://github.com/raderj89/blocipedia), I would like to run it now with rails s but am running into an error:

I did this;

- bundle install
- gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter

But still when i run rails s I get:

```
 Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql- adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

Any clues on what I should do to start a rails server with a downloaded project? Im working on a mac (os 10.8.5)

Comment: A link to that github project would be helpful.

Comment: And whether your on mac/windows/linux?

Comment: in gemfile do you have `gem pg`

Comment: @RajarshiDas, yes I do.

Comment: paste your config/database.yml

Answer (score 0):

Add the postgresql adapter to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg'
```

And then run `bundle install`